# Detect clicks of iframe elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe with the `id=phramecomp` which contains several elements such as links and button.Let us suppose i have a hyperlink inside iframe with the `id=donuts`.I want to set a click event for that hyperlink.How do i achieve that ?

This might be duplication of many questions but still anyone could tell me how to do this one ?

**Note:**

- iframe is on other php file by the name *orderonlinelist.php*
- I have included this iframe inside *orderonline.php* file and i am writing my click function  here.

  ```
   <iframe src="http://localhost/orderonline_list.php" name="phramecomp" id="phramecomp" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" ></iframe>
  ```

This is what i have included in my *orderonline.php* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can detect click events inside iframe

Lets suppose you an iframe having **id="Myframe"** and a image in you iframe having **id "Myimage"**

so for detecting click events inside Myframe in image Myimage you can

```
 $('#Myframe').loads(function()
 {

 var frame=$('#Myframe').contents();
 frame.find('#Myimage').click(function(){
 //do anything
 });
 });
```